# CSS rendering issue with meta tag

Tags: css, meta-tags

I have the following meta tag in my master file

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

All was working great until I created a scrolling div, code at bottom.  The site works but the scrolling div does not.  Remove the meta tag and the scroller looks great but the site no longer does.

We are using ie-8 internally without any chance of upgrading.

Any help here would be appreciated.

```css
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }

        .configContent 
        {
            margin:0; padding:0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .probesCT1  
        {
            width: 150px; 
            float:left;
            display: inline-table;
            background-color: lightsteelblue;
            }

        .probesCT2 { 

            height: 100%;
            float:left;
            display: inline-table;
            }

        .probesCT3 { 

            height: 30px;
            float:left;
            display: inline-table;
            }

        .pTbl  
        {
            overflow: auto; 
            height: 500px; 
            white-space: nowrap; 
            width:100%;
            }

        .pTbl2
        {
            overflow: hidden; 
            white-space: nowrap; 
            width:100%;
            height:30px;
            }

        .pRowHead
        {
            display:inline;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="configContent" style=' background: steelblue;'>
        <div class="probesCT1">
            Guided Nav Item List
        </div>

        <div class="probesCT2" style='background: grey;'>
            <div class="pTbl2">
                <div class='pRowHead'>Head 1</div>
                <div class='pRowHead'>Head 2</div>
                <div class='pRowHead'>Head 3</div>
                <div class='pRowHead'>Head 4</div>
                <div class='pRowHead'>Head 5</div>
                <div class='pRowHead'>Head 1</div>
            </div>

            <div class='pTbl' style='background: green;'>
                <div class='pRow'>1st para in pTbl</div>
                <div class='pRow'>some data that is really really long dfljkdhf glkjsdfghlskjdfhg slkjdfhglskjdfhglsk jd fhgslkjdfhg lksjdfhgskljdfhglsk jdfhg slkjdfh g lksjdfhglksjdfh slkjhfg lksjdhfg lksjdfhg lskdjhfglskdjhf glskdjhfg lsdfhg</div>
                <div class='pRow'>some data</div>
                <div class='pRow'>some data</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try setting your http-equiv to "Content-Type" and the charset equal to UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="IE8; charset=UTF-8" />
```